# Creating an exit button for Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, php, html, qualtrics

I'm working on a custom survey linking Qualtrics to Mturk so that workers would receive their own verification code at end of the survey. I have no problem [creating a custom end-of-the-survey page with random number as the validation code](https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-getting-great-survey-results-from-mturk-and-qualtrics-f5366f0bd880).

I'm struggling to create an "Exit Button" on each page of the survey, so that workers can quit at any time and the exit button would direct them to the end of the survey page.

I added a new question under every block and edited the html code with this:

```
<a href="#end of survey link" target="blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
<div style="display:block; background: #0077CC; padding: 8px 15px; border-radius:3px; color: #fff; width:95px; font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center">Exit</div>
</a>
```

The problem I'm having is I don't know exactly what to put in the href in order to link me to the end of survey page.

Comment: It depends entirely on how you advance the pages, which I'm assuming is done via JavaScript. As such, you'll probably need to include the relevant JavaScript as well, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to link directly to the last page, this will require some work to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have “Exit” questions already (I’m assuming the are Text Description questions), you could change them to Multiple Choice questions with an Exit choice that skips to end of survey. You can modify the look & feel of the questions with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that in the beginning but we've decided to add a button that looks a bit better. I ended up using the code I mentioned above and changing the href link to another survey. So basically creating another survey as the "end of the survey page". Since the validation code is already embedded, I could just use Query String to transfer the validation code via the href link.